# How to layout React Native views hierarchy inside native (Android) view?

Tags: android, user-interface, react-native, android-recyclerview, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to replace the React Native ViewPagerAndroid with RecyclerView plus custom LayoutManager. Please find below a picture of what I'm trying to achieve, the red and blue boxes below the text are there only to describe the problem better.

[image: Desired layout]

The picture below is what I get instead.

[image: Wrong layout]

The text view continue out of the containing box (the vertical white box) and the blue box layout is also out of the latter. By using the LayoutInspector, I see that the text box width and the blue box right edge are equal to the screen width even if I call the `measure` and `layout` methods on the React Native views.

Below a screenshot of the views hierarchy.

[image: Annotated View Hierarchy]

How to make React Native properly measure (and layout) the views in their container?